# How do you interpret it? (u∈Σ∗)

Tags: regular-language

Here is the full rule
{a^k u a^k| k≥1, u∈Σ∗}

does this mean either single *a* or single *b* or any combinations of *a* and *b* from the language can be replaced in u?

So if k=1 then is it aaa | aba OR a(aba)a | a(ba)a
Thanks

Rahman

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is a regular language tag here so I included it

Answer (score 0):

This rule means every string in the language has the same number of `a`'s at the beginning as at the end, with whatever you want (including more `a`'s) between.

So `aaa`, `aba`, `aabaa` and `abaa` are all in the language (assuming `b` is in Σ).

In fact, it is enough that the string is at least 2 characters long and there is an `a` at either end (left as an exercise).